# Ack : specifying a word for searching

Tags: regex, grep, ack

My search term is

```bash
ack @RequestMapping("/example_path")
```

and bash is complaining with

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

How can I search for the above text from bash the easiest way. All my attempts to escape the characters have not brought results.

Comment: @Rafa escaped your search with single quotes, which told bash that you wanted those literal characters, and that you did not want it to expand those. Otherwise, you have to escape the special characters: `@RequestMapping\("/example_path"\)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```bash
ack '@RequestMapping\("/example_path"\)'
```

Or, as Andy suggested:

```bash
ack -Q '@RequestMapping("/example_path")'
```

Comment: If you don't want to worry about doing all the metacharacter escaping, you can do this: `ack -Q '@RequestMapping("/example_path")`.  `-Q` says "quote any metacharacters that might be in my string".  Note that you still have to quote the string from the shell.

Comment: Good one. I think a single quote is missing in the end of the command you gave. Should read: `ack -Q '@RequestMapping("/example_path")'`.

Comment: You're right.  Too bad I can't edit it any more. :-/